# Extracting x rows every n rows from a table in matlab

Tags: matlab, datatable, extract

I want to create a new table extracting `x` rows every `n` rows from my table.  For example if my table is:

```
1 2 
3 4
5 6
7 8
9 10
11 12
13 14
15 16
17 18
19 20
21 22
```

I want something like:

```
1 2
3 4
11 12
13 14
21 22
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an easy way by using `ismember` and `mod` to categorize the rows

```
n = 5;
x = 2;
b = a(logical(ismember(mod(0:size(a)-1,n),0:x-1)),:);
```

such that

```
>> b
b =

    1    2
    3    4
   11   12
   13   14
   21   22
```

**Data**

```
a = [1 2 
3 4
5 6
7 8
9 10
11 12
13 14
15 16
17 18
19 20
21 22];
```